# What is Google Play?

Tags: google-play

My first thought was that it is a game search engine. However, it is cluttered with Android apps and Google additionally advertises looking for more Android apps there. On the other hand, searching for google.books, I am redirected to google.play to buy them. So, Google Play is an online shop for everything. Which is right? Which information should I look for in Google Play? Can you filter the apps by supported OS? Can I filter away the ubiquitous Android games looking only for desktop games?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The **Google Play Store** is Google's online shop for Android apps, music, movies & TV shows, e-books and e-magazines, and some Google devices.

Not for everything. Certainly not for desktop software.

See also: [Introduction to Google Play](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/2844886?ref_topic=2803017)

Let me see if I can clarify.

Google Play is where you...

- buy e-books for [Google Play Books](https://play.google.com/books) ([Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.books))
- buy magazines for [Google Play Magazines](https://play.google.com/magazines) ([Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.magazines))
- buy music for [Google Play Music](https://play.google.com/music/) ([Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.music))
- buy/rent movies and television shows for [Google Play Movies](https://play.google.com/movies) ([Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.videos))
- download/buy [apps for your Android device](https://play.google.com/apps)
- buy some [Google-branded devices](https://play.google.com/store/devices)

They don't sell anything else there, and I would expect any expansions to be along the same lines. You can download your music DRM-free, but the other media (books, movies, magazines) are locked to the service.

In other words, it's for Google products, or *content* for Google products.

Comment: Are movies, e-books, TV-shows and music also Android-based? I just cannot understand the rationale to eliminate the non-android apps from the search, especially if you are not focused on Andoid apps? It must be some mistake here. Therefore, I ask for explicit confirmation that books, movies and audio-tracks are not Android specific and only non-android apps are carved out.

Comment: Not Android-based per se, but that's most likely where you're most likely to consume them. You need to use Google Books, Google Movies, Google Magazines, and Google Music to consume each of those items. Those are Android apps as well as available in your desktop browser.

Comment: Thanks. I have discovered once a Triple Town game there and mistakenly decided that they provide thomething for online and Desktop.

Comment: You're not confusing it with the [Chrome Webstore](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/), are you?

Comment: Thanks for the reference. The fact that I could not play Triple Town anymore at Google Play is one reason that puzzeled me very strongly and motivated to write this question.

Comment: Triple Town was also one of the games offered on Google+ which are now being retired.