# Google Play vs Chrome web store

Tags: google-play-store, chrome-web-store

What is the difference between Google Play and Chrome Web Store? Both of these places allow users to download web apps and games.

Comment: See also: [What is the Google Play?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/46001)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Google Play Store](http://play.google.com/store) allows you to download and purchase Android apps, as well as music, movies, TV shows, e-books and magazines, and some Android devices and accessories.

The [Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/) allows you to download and purchase apps, extensions and themes for your [Google Chrome](http://chrome.google.com) browser (or Chrome OS device).

Comment: so google play is for android? but it seems i can access google play apps on chrome too. that was the basis of confusion for me.

Comment: Where? Which ones? I don't see any non-Android apps there.

Comment: Sorry...you are right..i am mistaken